# Create Dynamic Menu based on the ID of right clicked DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

I want to Create Dynamic Menu based on the ID of right clicked DOM element.   so that I can show the Menu for particular user eg: "Label For 23"

I am using the Context Menu something like this,

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: 'tr',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                var temp = $(this);
                if (key == "Rebate") DoInvoice();
            },
            items: {
                "Credit Note": { name: "Credit Note " },
            "Full Refund": { name: "Full Refund " },
            "Partial Refund": { name: "Partial Refund " },
            "Rebate": { name: "Rebate " }
                }
            });
```

Currently I am getting the Context Menu on right click as shown in the Image below,
[image]

But I want to show that in Format like

```
"Credit Note For 130",
"Full Refund For 130",
"Partial Refund For 130",
"Rebate For 130"
```

Please help me on this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var userid;
// Get the ID, when rightclick event is fired & set the ID to above variable.

items: {
                "Credit Note For"+ userid : { name: "Credit Note " },
            "Full Refund For"+ userid : { name: "Full Refund " },
            "Partial Refund For"+ userid : { name: "Partial Refund " },
            "Rebate For"+ userid : { name: "Rebate " }
                }
```

Comment: Its not working.  
And I want to use 'ID' which is in the Background & not in this kind.

Comment: This is not working,  
The code you have given throws the exceptions.

Comment: Do you succeeded in getting the `userid` value?